# How should I diagnose "too many redirects" error for some clients when I see "200 OK?"

Tags: wordpress, 301-redirect, too-many-redirects

I have some unusual behaviour with a wordpress page and the redirects, but I'm not sure what exactly is happening. I'm not allowed to mention the real domain here in public as the project is under development.

In my own chrome developer tools I see a direct 200 success.
Some but not all other users report a "too many redirects" error.

Question now is what is the best way to diagnose this? some reporting users use mobile app browsers, so no dev tools I could ask them.

We don't use any special htaccess rules, and also no Wordpress plugin I'm aware of doing redirects.

Comment: Note for others who may run into this: never forget to check if your customer (domain owner) moved DNS to cloudflare without telling you. issue solved.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, for example, with an external tool like https://httpstatus.io/.
just enter the URL you want to start with. The result will then show you whether the page could be opened directly with a 2xx code, or whether there are one or more redirects (301) in between.

It is common, for example, that the request for `www.example.com` is redirected to `https://www.example.com` first. And/or another redirect to another URL.

Comment: thanks! this is interesting because it shows a different redirect sequence that what I can see in my own Browsers developer tools. Looks like this sequence can cause some issues in the code logic running behind.

Answer (score 0):

### Confirm the test URL

Make sure you are testing the same URL that your users are having problems with.   Ask for screenshots from the users if you have too.   At the very least, make sure you are testing all common variations with and with `www`, `https`, or trailing slashes:

- `http://example.com/some-page/`
- `https://example.com/some-page/`
- `http://www.example.com/some-page/`
- `https://www.example.com/some-page/`
- `https://example.com/some-page`
- `http://example.com/some-page`
- `http://www.example.com/some-page`
- `https://www.example.com/some-page`

If you are using URL parameters or alternate domains, you will also need to test with and without those.

### Clear your browser cache

Both redirects and OK pages are stored in browser cache.   When you test, make sure that you clear your browser cache.

Similarly, if a user tested your site when it redirected differently, they may need to clear their cache before your site works again.   For example if you previously redirected `example.com` to `www.example.com` when the user tested before, but now you are redirecting `www.example.com` to `example.com`, the user won't be able to use your site without clearing their cache.

### Clear your cookies

Your site may behave differently based on cookies.  For example non-logged-in users may be getting redirects that you don't get when you are logged in.   You should clear your cookies to test.  Then try logging in or otherwise perform actions that set the cookies.

### Use testing tools rather than your browser

I recommend testing with the command line program [curl](https://curl.se/).  I usually test redirects with the `--head` command line option that instructs it to fetch the URL and only show the headers.  That will let you see the HTTP status and any `Location:` header with the redirect location:

```
$ curl --head http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: https://example.com/
```

Comment: Thank you for the extended answer. Will follow it.